# web.py templator passed jsons not being parsed correctly in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, web.py

I am using web.py and templetor and passing a variable full of jsons to javascript embedded in the templetor file. These jsons are to be consumed by D3.

```
 Python Code
           for row in rs:
                    #z['time'] = row.gps                                                                      
                    z['year'] = count + 2000
                    z['value'] = row.br
                    allrows.append(z)
                    count = count+1
                    if count > 5: break;
            p = json.dumps(allrows)
            return render.index(p)
```

Now this is supposed to be consumed in the templetor file:

```
$def with (data)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<div id="bar-demo"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" id="bar-demo-js">
var data = JSON.parse($data)
```

This seems to run into errors -- (as per firefox)
SyntaxError: invalid property id
[Break On This Error]

var data = JSON.parse([{"value": 151.47999999999999, "year":...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to call JSON.parse because it is already object and not a string in JavaScript. Just var data=$data is enough.